# Positioning a component on top of a tabview fails

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to position a `commandButton` on top of `tabview` header ?

I tried out this but failed to position the `commandButton` on top of `tabview`. Instead the `commandButton` gets hidden by the `tabview`

```
        <h:commandButton value="View all" style=" float:right;  z-index: 1000;" />

        <p:tabView style=" z-index: 5;" >

            <p:tab ...>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab ...>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add [`position:absolute;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to your `<h:commandButton>` style it will be on top of the `<p:tabView>`.

Comment: Absolute position elements ignore the float property.  You'll have to use [left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) or [right](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) properties to position horizontally.